# How do you access variables from within a Module from a class

Tags: ruby

Would appreciate someone's help here.

I've got the following situation:

```
module Tester
  def testing
    x = "This works"
  end
end


class Dog 
  include Tester

  puts  x
end
```

When I try to access the variable from within the class Dog (`puts x`), I get an error of `undefined variable x`. Can anyone tell me how I can get access to it?

Comment: `x` in this context is a local variable scoped inside the `testing` method. It will be inaccessible outside of that scope. That being said even if it were an instance variable you would not be able to perform puts inside the `Dog` class in this fashion. You may benefit from some reading rather than someone solving your issue for you [Small Blog Post on Ruby Instance Variables](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)

Comment: As I said I would like assistance and not a lecture on what to read. If there is another way to access this variable, I would appreciate if an experienced Rubyist could assist.

Comment: @user4219550 you can access it with `puts Dog.new.testing`, but your commentary is very unpleasant. You should really follow books/articles to understand what you are doing instead of asking so simple things.

Comment: not unpleasant. just being quite honest. :)

Comment: well from an honesty standpoint "...if you teach a [woman] to fish...". Right now you are just asking for fish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby supports class variables in modules, so you can define any class variable for your module, just like this:

```
Module Tester
  @@x = 'default' 
  def testing
      @@x = "This works"
  end

  def get_x
    @@x
  end
end


class Dog
  include Tester
  puts  @@x # get_x
end

#=> default
```

If you want "This works" text to be displayed, you need to call first the `testing` method:

```
Tester.testing
puts Tester.get_x #=> "This works"
```